# Realm, Cannot register notification blocks from within write transactions

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, realm

I'm using a function to save a realm object to my server. It's called using `DataManager().updatedCategory(~InsertCategory~)`. The implementation goes like this;

```swift
    func updatedCategory(_ c: Category) {
        guard let realm = try? Realm() else { return }
        guard let category = realm.object(ofType: Category.self, forPrimaryKey: c.id) else { return }
        do {
            try realm.write {
                c.updatedAt = Date()
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        dbCategories.document(category.id).updateData(category.dictionaryValue())
    }
```

This function is being called after using a `realm.write` block. It's not in another write block and even the UI is being updated before this is called. I can't figure out what's causing this error, since there's no notification being registered.

Comment: From where is this function called?

Answer (score 0):

I think this

```
try realm.write {
   c.updatedAt = Date()
}
```

should be

```
try realm.write {
   category.updatedAt = Date()
}
```

also, this

```
dbCategories.document(category.id).updateData(category.dictionaryValue())
```

looks like you're also attempting to write data to realm (?). If so, it needs to be within a write closure. If not, clarify what that does so I can update the answer.

Lastly, this is a bit unclear

```
This function is being called after using a realm.write block.
```

You can't embed a write closure within another, and adding observers should occur outside of a write closure as well - the error indicates the observer is being attached within a closure

Comment: Ah I'm sorry I see the confusion, I'll update my answer